# iOS equivalent to Gboard filling Google-managed passwords

Tags: keyboard, password, google-chrome, google

How can I get the passwords which are managed by my Google Chrome, when logging to non-web apps on iPhone?

On Android I know users can use it from Gboard.

I don't want to use Gboard keyboard on iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Settings → Passwords → AutoFill Passwords and check Allow Filling From: Chrome.